# robot framework - Clear Element Text keyword is not working

Tags: selenium, robotframework

We have a text field with the html structure as below.

```
<input class="css-1npmunl" name="some.name" aria-label="New Employee ID" data-qa="some.data" placeholder="" value="TEST1" type="Text">
```

The inbuilt Selenium2Library keyword `Clear Element Text    ${Field_Locator}` doesn't clear the text field as expected. In fact, the field gets cleared for a moment and when I do some other operation after that, like clicking a  `Save` button, the field value is re-populated again with the same value (`TEST1`) (`value` attribute contains the actual value of the field).

But when we do the same operation manually, it works as expected. When i checked the DOM using the developer tools, it seems, the Clear Element Text keyword doesn't actually makes the value of the `value` attribute to empty. But on doing manually, the value of the `value` attribute is blanked out.

Comment: Work around is passing EMPTY to the field as follows
```Input Text    <locator>    ${EMPTY}```

Comment: 1st option using `document.getElementsByName('some.name')[0].value = ' ';` 2nd option using `document.getElementById("some.name").removeAttribute("value");`

Comment: Thank you for the solutions. Unfortunately, both of the solutions provided above didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've ran into the same issue a couple of times (React is always at the bottom of it! :) and tried different things. Setting an empty value as suggested in the comments sometimes works, but fails at random.

At the end, I've settled at a "direct" solution - sending as many backspace characters as the length of the current value. A side effect is this is also close to a normal user interaction :); the real side effect is this is slower than a `Clear Element Text` call, can take a couple of seconds for longer text.

Here's a sample how to do it in RF:

```
${value}=     Get Element Attribute   ${Field_Locator}      value
${backspaces count}=    Get Length      ${value}
Run Keyword If    """${value}""" != ''    # if there's no current value - no need to slow down by an extra SE call
...     Repeat Keyword  ${backspaces count +1}  Press Key  ${Field_Locator}   \\08    # this is the code for the backspace key; "backspaces count +1" - just too be sure :)
```

Comment: Yeah, this worked. Thank you. Is there any reason for having multiple double-qoutes """${value}""". Just wanted to know.

Comment: Yes, that's a precaution against any values that are having quotes themselves - in python a string value that's surrounded with triple quotes can have quotes (and newlines) characters, without producing a syntax error (try it in a REPL). As I don't always know what the value-to-clear is going to be, that's a bit of a defense.

Comment: super answer !! @Todor, you just nailed it !!

Comment: Works great! Maybe just fix the depreciation warning:
[ WARN ] Keyword 'SeleniumLibrary.Press Key' is deprecated. use `Press Keys` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Since the poster has replied that he/she got their code working, but that answer did not help me; here is my answer.

I ran into exactly the same issue; using `Clear Element Text` did clear the textfield on the screen, but after submitting the form, the validation still failed.

The `Input text ${EMPTY}` dit not work for me either.

The way I got it working was by putting some new text in, and immediately removing it again, by using 
`Press Keys [locator] A+BACKSPACE`. I read many answers that find the length of the string, and were backspace'ing that many times. But instead I just simply press the 'a' on the keyboard, and then remove that 'a' again using the backspace.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like some frameworks will have trouble clearing some text fields. In these cases, I would create a keyword similar to this:

```
Clear Text Field

  [Arguments]  ${inputField}
  press keys  ${inputField}  CTRL+a+BACKSPACE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

Press Keys ${element}   CTRL+A+DELETE

It worked with me, i hope it can help you too

Answer (score 1):

You can use For loop to solve this problem.
Like this

```
 FOR  ${_}  IN RANGE    0  9 
    Press Keys        ${locator}      BACKSPACE
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it other than using "Clear Element Text" keyword. I would suggest to use "Press Keys" keyword to select all text in the text field. Then, erase it by pressing "BACKSPACE" key.

Sample RF script as follows:

```
Press Keys          [locator]               CTRL+a
Press Keys          [locator]               BACKSPACE
Input Text          [locator]               ${new_text}
Click Button        ${save_button}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more workaround :

press key        ${web_text_email_id}        \\1

press key        ${web_text_email_id}       \\127

input text       ${web_text_email_id}        ${user_name}

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this case still a big of an issue with recent updates on Selenium 4 and corresponding Robot framework Selenium Librarys. but "Press Key" is not deprecated and keyword "Press Keys" is working seamlessly. But actually I have noticed something that might be interesting. when I was using the press keys of CTRL+a or COMMAND+a (depending on the OS) then calling backspace on another keyword I have noticed that my selection got lost and only the last character was removed. So I made my action in one keyowrd and my script looks like below:

```
Clear Entry Field
  [Arguments]  ${textField}
  Press Keys  ${textField}   COMMAND+a  BACKSPACE
```

Hope this helps.