# Selenium clear input field different behavior

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Our customer uses the robot framework to test the application we are developing. I have the strange phenomena that they have a test that is working on their machines but not in our test execution environment and not on my local working station.
I already narrowed it down to a single selenium keyword.

```
   SeleniumLibrary.Clear Element Text    ${elementXpath}
```

In general this is simply a python wrapper for

`driver.find_element_by_id('foo').clear()`

I already found out that the selenium function itself doesn't work as expected and found already this question.
[robot framework - Clear Element Text keyword is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53518481/robot-framework-clear-element-text-keyword-is-not-working)

The workarounds mentioned in this question works for me. But it is hard for me to sell the customer to change their keywords, if it is working for them.

I already checked the libraries and the browser version. All the same. I hoped someone has an explanation, why this keyword could work differently in some environment.

Chrome 84
Chromedriver 84

Comment: Going to suspect this is related to the handling of autocomplete fields only - which "can" be disabled in the test browser profile, but best handled for example by sending CTRL+'a' then sending BACKSPACE , literally.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Customer did not use the most recent chromedriver, but a very old version  2.40.565498. For some reason this driver does not have the issue described in https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6741.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not convince the client of the significant value of having a single test set that also validates in the early phases and environments of development, then this non-functioning statement should be the least of your worries. As the old adage goes: quality is not baked in afterwards, it's the result of validating every step of the way.

Without having detailed insight in the code base I'd recommend looking into `Set Library Search Order` [Documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Library%20Search%20Order) and perhaps adding a `Suite Setup` [Documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown) where you set this will allow you to make the test set compatible with your environment, without modifying the actual customer test files.

Comment: Okay. Maybe i forgot to mention, I would also like to understand it myself, why the keyword works on the one machine and not on the other. As far as I understand the issue with the keyword it should never have worked at all.

Comment: Can you add descriptions of the differences between the environments the client uses, your own local setup and the execution environment in your question through [edit].